# how to put every <li> in a new line?

Tags: html, css

I am making a review section for an item on my website, so to put the reviews and comment section, I used

```
<ul>
 <li>
 Comment code
 </li>
 <li>
 Comment code
 </li>
</ul>
```

inside the li items, there are divs inside divs. I made all the comments section as I like and everything is good.

The only problem I have is the comments ( li items) is in line with each other. I tried using

```
.review_bottom li{
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
}
```

but it did not change anything. I can fix it with br tags, but I can't because the br will either work on PC or Phones, it can't work perfectly with both.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply your class to your list:

```css
.review_bottom {
margin: 0;
padding :0;
    list-style: none;
}

.review_bottom li {
float: left; 
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="review_bottom">
 <li>
 Comment code
 </li>
 <li>
 Comment code
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: For some reason, it won't work with the float points I added. but that will fix it if there was no floating points.

Comment: The float command in CSS. That what happen when you take 3 programming languages together. You just mix them up.

Comment: If you want to inline the items set the li's to float: left and inline-block.

Comment: Nice, that fixed my problems. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to insert a line break after each item of the list.

```css
.review_bottom li {
  list-style: none;
}
.review_bottom li:after {
  content: "\A";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<ul class="review_bottom">
  <li>
    Comment code
  </li>
  <li>
    Comment code
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<ul>
 <li>
 Comment code
 </li><br>
 <li>
 Comment code
 </li><br>
</ul>
```

This is all you need for the Html code